# Preconfigure NOOBS for Wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-3, setup

I just found out that it's possible to configure the NOOBS package, for example editing the default username "pi", when you edit the os.json:

```
os/Raspbian/os.json
```

Is it also possible to parse a Wifi SSID and password, so the Pi (3) automatically connects to a Wifi network after finishing the setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NOOBS documentation is available at

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md

> Preconfiguring a WiFi network
>
> If you already know your WiFi details, you can preconfigure NOOBS to
>   use it straight away. Put a copy of your wpa_supplicant.conf file on
>   the NOOBS root partition and NOOBS will read it and store it in its
>   settings for all future uses.